# GeoNodes - Incremental Rotation object on curves

Tags: modifiers, node-editor, geometry-nodes, geometry

I have created a path array in Autodesk Alias where I can use an "Incremental Rotation" option and easily create the rendering shown in the reference image.

But I do not know how to implement this in Blender with Geometry Nodes to achieve the same result.

Thanks for your time and help.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want to achieve, but the example you showed is how I would solve it:

[image]

Here I use a NURBS curve as a base, and change the value for "Tilt" (*Curve Tilt*) at its points.

In Geometry Nodes you would then only have to convert this curve into points, and then get the corresponding rotation, which you can use directly when instantiating the objects.

Of course, you can use any kind of curve with this technique, including a circle:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.6+)*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

To me, the pattern on the reference just looks like a circle.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer and help, it's exactly the result of the image reference. I  wanted to know if I can adapt this solution to just a curves. But I will try with this solution ! :)